# Length limit of composite type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, variable-length, composite-types

I would need to set up a composite type to pack a large scale of complex structure.

So I want to ask if it has a limit of 8kb in PostgreSQL, or the limit is depend on what data it is composed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The maximum length of a single (text or bytea) column is 1GB. There is no 8kb limit for any data type in Postgres

Comment: Ah, I know that for user defined data type, there is a 8 byte limit if use plan storage strategy. So I am wondering if a composite type would have the same limitation? Or, each element would have its own limitation. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name